# update every row with a different random datetime of a range

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitestudio

The question asked here is

[Update every row with a random datetime between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456735/update-every-row-with-a-random-datetime-between-two-dates)

to update with the same datetime.

What I need is to update every row with a different random datetime within a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
strftime('%s', enddate) - strftime('%s', startdate)
```

you can get the difference in seconds between 2 datetimes.
With:

```
abs(random() % (strftime('%s', enddate) - strftime('%s', startdate) + 1))
```

you can get a random integer, greater or equal to `0`, that is less than or equal to the difference between the 2 datetimes in seconds.
What you can do is add this random number of seconds to the starting date of your range to create a random datetime within that range:

```
update tablename 
set datecol = datetime(
  startdate, 
  abs(random() % (strftime('%s', enddate) - strftime('%s', startdate) + 1)) || ' second'
)
```

`datecol` is the date column in your table
`startdate` and `enddate` are the boundaries of your range.

Comment: Really! Thank you. I did not understand what makes it to calculate datetime again with every row, but it does! I had tried similar things but it was calculating datetime only once, and updating all rows with that one value.

Comment: An update statement without a where clause updates all the rows of the table.